# Can Connect to 3G Modem via GSMComm but cannot see any SMS

Tags: sms

I'm trying to write an application that receives SMS messages into the app I'm developing (in C# if you care :).  Research indicates the best bet is to use GSMComm library.

I've downloaded the library and using the demo app I have managed to connect to the 3g modem (a Huawei E1756) but when I query it for SMS's received it comes back with 0.

Interestingly if I use the software that comes with the application then I can see the messages.

Anyone got any clues on why this would be?   Or other tips on how to retrieve the messages?

Cheers,
Kym

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the modem is setup, messages can be stored on either the SIM card or in phone memory.

I would check that the demo app is looking in both places for old messages.

Answer (score 1):

I use gammu's smsd which can write to a database which you can then use your c# with.

it is supports a wide array of phones and modems including many Huawei models

http://wammu.eu/phones/huawei/

It runs on windows and linux and has worked well for me.

http://wammu.eu/smsd/

the database has a simple inbox and outbox tables that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Try Clickatell to get an idea  http://www.clickatell.com/brochure/coverage.php